# Footer inflate not working on landscape Android

Tags: android, android-layout, footer, layout-inflater, landscape-portrait

I am having a somewhat awkward problem with a footer. 
I have a custom list of items that are loaded in pages. When you reach the last item it retrieves more items if available, that is when (while waiting) a footer inflates saying "Downloading". Of course it is removed after the items are downloaded.
The problem is that the way I am inflating the footer is working fine ONLY on potrait mode. When using landscape the footer just won't appear.

EDIT: The issue is when changing modes (landscape, potrait) while already on the activity. If I start in landscape from the beginning it works too.

This is the code I use to inflate the footer:

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.shops_list);
footerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_downloading, null, false);
lv.addFooterView(footerView);
```

This is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ListActivity"
android:background="@color/background" >

    <ProgressBar android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progress_list" 
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:indeterminateBehavior="cycle" />

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/generic_shops_list"
    android:background="@color/background" >

       <ListView
        android:id="@+id/shops_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@color/pallette_blue"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the footer:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="15dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_downloading_more"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="@string/downloading_more"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ProgressBar android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progress_downloading" 
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:indeterminateBehavior="cycle"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/message_downloading_more"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the full class also for more reference: [Class](http://pastebin.com/BRgbuKFX)

Answer (score 0):

You should always specify the parent layout when inflating views.

```
footerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_downloading, lv, false);
```

Comment: still crashing...besides this doesn't explain why it was already working on potrait but not on landscape

Comment: Crashing? Can i see a stack trace?

Comment: actually it doesn't crash there...it crashes when I remove it after the download is done and of course the footer was never inflated. But the inflate doesn't crash, it simply does not work properly.

Comment: Ah, where do you do the footer adding? Is it called when your start the download? You'll need to remember to re-add it when you rotate whilst a download is running as the whole UI is recreated.

Comment: I uploaded the full class here for more reference [link](http://pastebin.com/BRgbuKFX)